# MySQL Shorten Query - SELECT with mutliple OR choices

Tags: mysql

Here is the query I have

```
SELECT FB_TEXT
FROM `FB_DATA`
WHERE `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID = 1
```

What I want to do is allow multiple FB_TYPEID's so the query should be like:

```
AND FB_TYPEID = 1,2,7
```

1, 2, and 7 are the numbers I need allowed.  How can I write that without making a long query saying:

```
SELECT FB_TEXT
FROM `FB_DATA`
WHERE `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID = 1 OR `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID = 2 OR `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID = 7
```

Comment: The `IN ()` clause is what you need here.  `WHERE FB_MODELID IN (1,2,7)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of  `=` :

```
WHERE `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND FB_TYPEID IN (1,2,7)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!  I knew there had to be a way just wasn't sure what it was.

Answer (score 1):

The IN() operator is the right answer but if you dont want (or can't) use IN() you dont need to repeat the model id. This query is equivilent to the IN() solution.

```
SELECT FB_TEXT
FROM `FB_DATA`
WHERE `FB_MODELID` = "'.$sku_modelid.'" AND (FB_TYPEID = 1 OR FB_TYPEID = 2 OR FB_TYPEID = 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
WHERE `FB_MODELID` = ? AND FB_TYPEID IN (1,2,7)
```

(ps use placeholders in your queries to prevent SQL injection attacks)